# Is this cat safe of inbreeding?

Tags: cats

I would like to buy a cat (my first one) and I checked her for inbreeding and here are it's parents - https://pawpeds.com/db/?a=p&ids=3:1340035;2:1340037&g=5&p=sib&o=ajgrep

My question is, is it safe? Because with 4 generations there is 0% and with 5th generation 2.34% and then continue to raise.

Thanks for replies,
David